# When writing p-forms and p-vectors, is the increasing index values restriction $\vert i,j,\dots,k\vert$ equivalent to "unique sets" of index values?

Tags: combinatorics, tensors, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

This is my motivation.  In the case of $\mathbb{R}^3,$ the wedge product of two vectors is identical to the cross product.  The way I have written this for the first four expressions is consistent with the traditional form of the cross product. Note that the last term has $i=3,j=1.$
The remaining expressions show this to be equivalent to the typical form used in exterior calculus; where the vertical bars indicate that index values are to be taken over the range for which they are in increasing order.

\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{a}\wedge\mathfrak{b}= & \hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j}a^{i}b^{j}\\
= & \begin{pmatrix}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\left(a^{1}b^{2}-a^{2}b^{1}\right)\\
+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}\left(a^{2}b^{3}-a^{3}b^{2}\right)\\
+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\left(a^{3}b^{1}-a^{1}b^{3}\right)
\end{pmatrix}\\
= & \hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}c^{12}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}c^{23}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}c^{31}\\
=&\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}c^{12}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}c^{13}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}c^{23}\\
= & \hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{\vert i}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j\vert}\left(a^{i}b^{j}-a^{j}b^{i}\right)\\
= & \hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{\vert i}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j\vert}c^{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j}c^{ij}
\end{align*}

Now consider the case of two indices ranging over four values. There are six (unordered) sets.

$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}\Rightarrow \binom{4}{2}=\frac{4!}{4}=3!$$

Let $e=\pm 1$ and $f=\pm 1$.  Call those pairs equal to 1, even.

\begin{align*}
\left[ij\right]= & -\left[ji\right]\\
e= & \left[12\right]=\left[23\right]=\left[34\right]=\left[41\right]\\
-e= & \left[21\right]=\left[32\right]=\left[43\right]=\left[14\right]\\
f= & \left[13\right]=\left[24\right]\\
-f= & \left[31\right]=\left[42\right]
\end{align*}

The notation $\vert ij \vert$ now means to sum over even pairs. The first expanded sum uses $1=e=f$.  The second uses $1=e=-f.$

\begin{align*}
\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{\vert i}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j\vert}T^{ij}= & \begin{pmatrix}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}T^{12}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{4}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}T^{41}\\
+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}T^{23}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}T^{13}\\
+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{4}T^{34}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{4}T^{24}
\end{pmatrix}\\
= & \begin{pmatrix}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}T^{12}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{4}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}T^{41}\\
+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}T^{23}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}T^{31}\\
+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{4}T^{34}+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{4}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}T^{42}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Since both the wedge product and the tensor component toggle signs when the index order is reversed, the choice of which six unique pairs are designated "even" is irrelevant.  What matters is that we are summing over unique sets of index values.

It seems obvious to me that this generalizes to any number of indices and any range of index values.  I don't recall having ever seen that (apparent) fact stated.  Is it correct?

For example:

From Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, Exercise 4.12(b)
[image]

> $\dots$The final line here introduces the convention that a summation over indices enclosed between vertical bars includes only those terms with indices in increasing order.

**Could this be replaced by *'a summation over indices enclosed between vertical bars includes only terms with unique sets of index values',* without changing the meaning of the expression?**

This seems blatantly obvious to me (though working out an inductive proof is not immediately obvious).

And, even if it applies here, **is there a context in which this redefinition would produce a non-equivalent mathematical expression?**

Comment: We regard any scalar p-form defined by $$A_{j_1,\dots,j_p}dx^{j_1}\wedge\dots \wedge dx^{j_p}$$ where the $A_{j_1,\dots,j_p}$ is a completely skew symmetric typ $(0,p)$ tensor with $p\leq n$, as an element of a vector space of dimension $\binom{n}{p}$ whose basis elements relative to the given coordinate system on $X_n$ are represented by $dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{j_p}$, with $j_1<j_2<\dots <j_p$. The direct sum of these vector spaces ($p=0,1,\dots,n)$ *is* the Grassman Algebra.

Comment: And hence my question.  Will any unique selection of sets of index values suffice as a substitute for $j_1<j_2<\dots <j_p$?

Comment: I don't think I understand your eccentric notation and / or your question. Since $dx^j\wedge dx^h=-dx^h\wedge dx^j$ it is always true that $$A_jB_h\,dx^j\wedge  dx^h=\frac{1}{2}(A_jB_h-A_hB_j)\,dx^j\wedge dx^h$$This is the skew-symmetric part of the tensor $A_jB_h$ and since the most general 2-form is $$A_{jh}\,dx^j\wedge dx^h$$ we can, without loss of generality, assume the coefficients $A_{jh}$ to be the components of a skew-symmetric type $(0,2)$-tensor.

Comment: Maybe there is a hint in your headline, "increasing index restriction". There is no such restriction. The general p-form $$A_{j_1,\dots,{j_p}}\,dx^{j_1}\wedge dx^{j_2}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{j_p}$$ is of course summed over all possible values according to the summation convention. But as I explain above, you can, without loss of generality, use the components of a skew-symmetric tensor since the symmetric part cancel out.

Comment: I don't know if you're having me on, or missing my point.  The only things "eccentric" (to me) in my notation are the use of hats to emphasize the basis vectors are orthonormal. (which is superfluous in this context), and the square bracket notation, which I invented for the sake of discussion.  You are writing linear forms where I am writing polyvectors.  (See the Mathematical Appendix of Ciufolini and Wheeler) But the algebra is the same.

Comment: I'm sorry and I believe I understand your question. The point of using the combination where $j_1<\dots <j_p$ is, among other things, to make it easy to match it with the basis elements $dx^{j_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{j_p}$ without having to rewrite stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understand your question and the answer is simply Yes.

In an expression like $$\sum_{j_1<\dots< j_p}\delta^{h_1\dots h_p}_{j_1,\dots j_p}\,dx^{j_1}\wedge\dots \wedge dx^{j_p}=\frac{1}{p!}\delta ^{h_1\dots h_p}_{j_1\dots j_p}\,dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{jp}$$ we divide by $p!$ because among the $p!$ permutations of $p$ distinct integers $j_1,\dots j_p$ there is only one for which $j_1<j_2<\dots<j_p$. But of course you are free to pick one of the other $p!-1$ permutations if you are so inclined.

Further, for any $A_{h_1\dots h_p}$, **irrespective of symmetry or skew-symmetry properties**, we have
$$A_{h_1\dots h_p}\,dx^{h_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{h_p}=\sum_{j_1<\dots <j_p} \delta^{h_1\dots h_p}_{j_1\dots j_p}A_{h_1\dots h_p}\,dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{j_p}$$

And again, if you want, you can pick another permutation. This works because both $\delta_{h_1\dots h_p}^{j_1\dots j_p}$ and $dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{j_p}$ are skew-symmetric in $j_1,\dots j_p$.

Comment: I've believed this to be true for years, but I don't recall having read it anywhere.  For me, dogmatically following the increasing index formulation hides natural symmetries.  The case of the cross-product is an example. The third term looks different from the others using increasing index formulation. "Beauty is the first test: there is no permanent place in the world for ugly mathematics." ~~ G. H. Hardy